# Bootstrap: align input with button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Why don't buttons and inputs align well in Bootstrap?

I tried something simple like:

```
<input type="text"/><button class="btn">button</button>
```

The button is about `5px` lower than the input in chrome/firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 605, accepted):

### Twitter Bootstrap 4

In Twitter Bootstrap 4, inputs and buttons can be aligned using the `input-group-prepend` and `input-group-append` classes (see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#button-addons)

#### Group button on the left side (prepend)

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

#### Group button on the right side (append)

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Twitter Bootstrap 3

As shown in the answer by @abimelex, inputs and buttons can be aligned by using the `.input-group` classes (see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)

#### Group button on the left side

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

#### Group button on the right side

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

This solution has been added to keep my answer up to date, but please stick your up-vote on [the answer provided by @abimelex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592382/681807).

---

### Twitter Bootstrap 2

Bootstrap offers an `.input-append` class, which works as a wrapper element and corrects this for you:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input name="search" id="search"/>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
```

As pointed out by @OleksiyKhilkevich in his answer, there is a second way to align `input` and `button` by using the `.form-horizontal` class:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <input name="search" id="search"/>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
```

#### The Differences

The difference between these two classes is that `.input-append` will place the `button` up against the `input` element (so they look like they are attached), where `.form-horizontal` will place a space between them.

**-- Note --**

*To allow the `input` and `button` elements to be next to each other without spacing, the `font-size` has been set to `0` in the `.input-append` class (this removes the white spacing between the `inline-block` elements). This may have an adverse effect on font-sizes in the `input` element if you want to override the defaults using `em` or `%` measurements.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I feel like something is going wrong here. Surely I am not the first person to wish that bootstrap components lined up with form elements.

Comment: @pguardiario - you are completely right. It did seem wrong and after slapping my brain I remembered the `.input-append` class.

Comment: It seems strange that you would need a wrapper class to do this. Shouldn't they line up by default?

Comment: @opsb if they took up the same amount of vertical space then yes they would. However input fields in twitter bootstrap have a `margin-bottom: 9px` but the buttons do not so they do not take up the same vertical space. Since both elements have a `middle` vertical alignment, the button is offset due to the difference. Using the `.input-append` wrapper removes this margin-bottom value.

Comment: Right, I guess that it would break other form layouts if they had the same vertical height by default.

Comment: The example jsfiddle link seems died. Could you please re-post it again? Thanks so much

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The Bootstrap 3 answer worked for me. Are the docs out of date? When I was trying to use the Bootstrap CSS form docs it said to use a `form-inline` class on the form element.

Comment: How can this be done in 4? It has a small over edge on the in put with Bootstrap 4 and without doing a group.

Answer (score 221):

**Bootstrap 5**

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Go</button>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 3 & 4**

you may use the [input-group button property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups-basic) to apply the button direct to the input-field.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Take a look at [BS4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/button-group/) or [BS5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/#button-addons) Input-Group doc for many more examples.

[image: example for bs3 input group button]

Comment: Other ones did not work for me, this one did however, just the way I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: For me it did not work if creating an extra span tag to allocated the class, but it worked if I added that class to the div tag: `<div class="form-group input-group-btn">`

Comment: This answer is outdated for BS4, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 38):

Just the heads up, there seems to be special CSS class for this called `form-horizontal`

input-append has another side effect, that it drops font-size to zero

Comment: +1 good spot - I had to look into why they used `font-size: 0` and learnt something new :) Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

Use **.form-inline** = This will left-align labels and inline-block controls for a compact layout 
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hSuy4/292/

```
<div class="form-inline">
<input type="text">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="submit">
</div>
```

**.form-horizontal** = Right align labels and float them to the left to make them appear on the same line as controls which is better for 2 column form layout.

```
(e.g. 
Label 1: [textbox]
Label 2: [textbox]
     : [button]
)
```

Examples: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Comment: I can confirm that `form-inline` works for Bootstrap 3.  Thanks.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I needed for a troublesome form!

Comment: It seems .form-inline works only within viewports at least 768px wide: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Answer (score 17):

I tried above all and end-up with few changes which I would like to share. Here's the code which works for me (find the attached screenshot):

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search text">
    <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0;">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

[image]

If you want to see it working, just use below code in you editor:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search text">
                  <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0;">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which Bootstrap version is this for? And which problem does it cause not using `style="width:0;"` ?

Comment: If you don't use width:0 then this will take full width of the page.

Comment: bootstrap way would to wrap with a col-element like `<div class="col-md-4">` No need for for `width: 0`

Comment: i set because i don't want input controls to take full width of the screen

Answer (score 6):

I was also struggling with same issue. The bootstrap classes I use are not working for me. I came up with an workaround, as below:

```
<form action='...' method='POST' class='form-group'>
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="text" name="..." 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Search People..."
        style="width:280px;max-width:280px;display:inline-block"/>

    <button type="submit" 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        style="margin-left:-8px;margin-top:-2px;min-height:36px;">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
     </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Basically, I overrode the display property of class "form-control", and used other style properties for correcting the size and position.

Following is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

Answer (score 4):

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the above codes and none of them fixed my issues. Here is what worked for me. I used input-group-addon.

```
<div class = "input-group">
  <span class = "input-group-addon">Go</span>
  <input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder="you are the man!">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related, unless you have similar code but I just noticed a strange behaviour to form-inline, bootstrap 3.3.7

I did not use row and cells for this as it is a desktop project, if the opening tag was below table (in this case):

```
<table class="form-inline"> 
<form> 
<tr>
```

Form elements would stack.

Switch and it properly lined up.

```
<form>
<table class="form-inline">
<tr>
```

Safari 10.0.2 and latest Chrome did not make any differences. Maybe my layout was wrong but it is not very forgiving.

Answer (score 1):

Take an input float as left. Then take the button and float it right.
You can clearfix class when you take more than one to distance.

```
<input style="width:65%;float:left"class="btn btn-primary" type="text" name="name"> 
<div style="width:8%;float:left">&nbsp;</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
<div class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom:10px"> </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
style="padding-top: 8px"
```

Use this to shift your div up or down in your row.  Works wonders for me.