# button alignign with input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

here is my code :

```
<div class="input-append">

                        <input name="username" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter your username..." type="text" class="input-large" id="id_username" />


                        <input name="password" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter your password..." type="password" class="input-large" id="id_password" />

<button class="btn btn-mini">Envoyer</button>
     </div>
```

here is the result :

[image: here is the result :]

how to align the button with the fields please ?

Regards
Bussiere

Comment: Please provide your css code for more

Comment: Are you asking how to align them vertically (so they are the same height)?

Comment: What additional CSS are you using? The HTML in your question - when coupled with Twitter Bootstrap - does not look like your screen shot: http://jsfiddle.net/XTuUc/

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap: align input with button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615872/bootstrap-align-input-with-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually set the height to the same value

```
.input-large,
.btn-mini {
   height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: I had to put :<style>
.input-large,
.btn-mini {
   height: 20px;
} 
</style> Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set one of the "height" properties on each of them in CSS to get them the same height alignment, if I follow your question properly.

I am not a CSS guru but here is an example that should work :

```
<style>
.equal_height input, .equal_height button { height: 40px; }
</style>

<div class="input-append equal_height">
     <input name="username" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter your username..." type="text" class="input-large" id="id_username" />
     <input name="password" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter your password..." type="password" class="input-large" id="id_password" />
      <button class="btn btn-mini">Envoyer</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Note : that is a horrible naming convention I used, this is just an example to get you started. :)