# Aligning text box and button, bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've had the following issue occur with a bootstrap-styled text field and input button many times. Notice that they are not vertically aligned:

[image]

How do I align these two elements? Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="span6">
    <input type="text" placeholder="email"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Sign up</button>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap: align input with button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615872/bootstrap-align-input-with-button)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In order to complete that, you must use proper [Twitter Bootstrap classes for forms](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).

In this case, that is `.form-inline` class.

Here is proper markup:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email"/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/YpXvT/42/

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="navbar-form pull-left">
  <input type="text" class="span2">
  <button class="btn">Sign up</button>
</div>
```

copied from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

or

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text"/>
    <button class="btn">Sign up</button>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="text"/>
    <button class="btn">Sign up</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="monEmail@domaine.fr">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

change css for class input-group-btn in boostrap-min: vertical-align =>top
it s work for me