# Make text input and button in same row with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using basic file upload bootstrap-fileupload.js to give me a filename and button and want to repeat the format with a text input and button.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Source File Name</label>
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="form-control uneditable-input"><i class="icon-file fileupload-exists"></i> 

            </div>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
                    <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                    <input type="file" class="file-input"/></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <form id="frmOptions" method="post" class="form-inline span12">

 <div class="row-fluid">   
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">File Name on Upload</label>
    <div class="input-group ">
        <input id="uploadname" type="text" class="form-control">
        <a class="btn btn-default go inline">Upload to DocMan</a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</form>
```

Page hosted here https://googledrive.com/host/0B90FGJizRd-gbm1JRUswYUY5dE0/bootstrap/
I have tried variations of this with no effect. Basically I want two similar looking full width rows, each with a text field and a button. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

1. Remove class "form-inline" from the form
2. Add class "input-group-btn" to the button

Resulting html:

```
<form id="frmOptions" method="post" class="span12">
    <div class="row-fluid">   
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">File Name on Upload</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="uploadname" type="text" class="form-control">
                <a class="input-group-btn btn btn-default go inline">Upload to DocMan</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This makes the button float all the way to the right. How can I force it to stay next to the text input?

Answer (score 19):

You use the input group

```
<div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: hmm doesn't work for me.. the button goes to a new line

Comment: Note: This works with Bootstrap 3. If it does not work for you, check if you are using an older Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap it inside a div with the "navbar-form" class. That will put everything inside inline.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to override the `display:block;` style of the class form-control. I have posted sample code in following reply:

[bootstrap: align input with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615872/bootstrap-align-input-with-button/38885738#38885738)