# How to align a button with class btn with form input element with class form-control from twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I searched a lot and FOUND a few references on STACK but I am posting this anyways (it is a "duplicate" question **but the accepted answer doesn't seem to work** in any of my cases)

**STACK LINK:**
[bootstrap: align input with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615872/bootstrap-align-input-with-button)

I can't seem to display a button inline with form-control element (input text),,

I have three versions of the same thing

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Cu9w/9/

```
<div class="form-inline col-xs-4">
    <label class="control-label">New Tag: </label>
    <input class="form-control"/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</div>

    <br/><br/>

<div class="form-horizontal col-xs-4">
    <label class="control-label">New Tag: </label>
    <input name="search" id="search" class="form-control"/>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>

    <br/><br/>

<div class="input-append col-xs-4">
    <label class="control-label">New Tag: </label>
    <input name="search" id="search" class="form-control"/>
    <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
```

I found a variety of similar ideas and answers but no matter what I do, they do not work..

My fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Cu9w/9/

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Where do you want to align the button? To the right? Maybe putting it next to the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's column properties to specify the layout you would like WITHIN YOUR `.form-inline`, like so:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TbXms/1/).

If that's the property you would like all your input/button pairs to have, I would recommend using an `&:extend()` and a specific `.input-button` class in your LESS, but that's how you would go about solving this problem.