# Centering navbar-brand image with centered navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just learning **Bootstrap 3** and I want to use that in my website so it's still comfortable to access from mobile devices.

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

but this is as far as I get.
This is the code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenanchristian/6sc7c6t2/)

```css
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    height:30px;
}

.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-brand:focus {
   text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-brand > img {
   display: inline-block;
   margin:auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
}

.navbar .divider-vertical {
   height: 50px;
   margin: 0 9px;
   border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
   border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.navbar-inverse .divider-vertical {
   border-right-color: #222222;
   border-left-color: #111111;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-collapse .nav > .divider-vertical {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  
   <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
     <div class="container">    
       <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="image/nav_logo.png"/></a> 
       <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>   
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">    
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
      </ul>    
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>    
       </div> 
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
 <div class = "container">
  <div class="social">
     <a class="pull-left icon" href="#" data-icon = "f"></a>
     <a class="pull-left icon" href="#"  data-icon = "i"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    max-width: 480px; /**change the max width to what ever you want you can add it in media query too*/
    margin: 0 auto;  /**center the menu*/
}
```

[live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6sc7c6t2/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I would have done this:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
}
.img-holder {  
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
ul,li {margin:0;padding:0;}
ul {
  width: 304px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
li {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
.left-ul {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -350px;
}
.right-ul {
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <ul class="left-ul">
     <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>PRODUCT</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="img-holder"></div>
  <ul class="right-ul">
     <li>BLOG</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but you could try using input group classes: [bootstrap: align input with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615872/bootstrap-align-input-with-button?rq=1).

In general, if you know the height of a block element, if you set its line height to that height you'll get one line that is centered vertically in that space; just watch out for items going to two lines or more, then it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a few changes to both your CSS and HTML.

HTML-wise, make all the items (inlcluding the image), `navbar` `li` items and remove the `left` and `right` navbar classes.

Then you will need to center the `navbar` using in its uncollapsed state by applying `text-align` on the parent and unfloating the children, using:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }    
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3u7pLxe/)

```css
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 30px;
}
.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-brand > img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
}
.navbar .divider-vertical {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 9px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
.navbar-inverse .divider-vertical {
  border-right-color: #222222;
  border-left-color: #111111;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-collapse .nav > .divider-vertical {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse ">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product</a>

        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="image/nav_logo.png" />
          </a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="social">
      <a class="pull-left icon" href="#" data-icon="f"></a>
      <a class="pull-left icon" href="#" data-icon="i"></a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```