# How to align a bootstrap button to the right of a select option in a bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to align the bootstrap button to the right as per the diagram. Please note I am using Bootstrap Panels and `form-horizontal`:
[image]

By default the buttons are put beneath the options. what I have tried:

`<button style="float: right" type="button" id="show-contact-modal-button" class="btn btn-primary">`

This aligns the button to the right but still beneath the dropdown.

`<div class=text-right><button ...>`

This actually completely removes the button :-)

Here is the more complete HTML:

```
...

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="http://host/lead">

...
<!-- Contacts -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="contact_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">Contact</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="contact_id" id="contacts-select" class="form-control" title="">
                            <option value="1"
                                >
                    Eugene van der Merwe</option>
                            <option value="2"
                                >
                    Person B</option>
                            <option value="3"
                                >
                    Person C</option>
                    </select>

        <button type="button" id="show-contact-modal-button" class="btn btn-primary">
            Add contact
        </button>

            </div>
</div>
<!-- // Contacts -->

<!-- Referrer -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="referrer_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">Referrer</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="referrer_id" id="referrers-select" class="form-control" title="">
                            <option value="1"
                                >Eugene van der Merwe</option>
                            <option value="2"
                                >Person B</option>
                            <option value="3"
                                >Person C</option>
                            <div class=text-right>
                <button style="float: right" type="button" id="show-referrer-modal-button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Add referrer
                </button>
                </div>
        </select>



            </div>
</div>
<!-- // Referrer -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Create
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: give me link where you add this or show a live demo

Comment: please provide fiddle link

Comment: Col-md-8 gives a width to the div which is completely taken by the select menu.. If u reduce the width of select menu small enough to fit the button in the div then it can get align.. If it doesn't work then add disply:flex to the div.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615872/bootstrap-align-input-with-button :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can leverage Bootstrap's [`input-group`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups), and `input-group-addon` classes. Then we just need to update the styling to handle a button inside.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="http://host/lead">
    <!-- Contacts -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contact_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">Contact</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-group">
                <select name="contact_id" id="contacts-select" class="form-control" title="">
                    <option value="1">
                        Eugene van der Merwe</option>
                    <option value="2">
                        Person B</option>
                    <option value="3">
                        Person C</option>
                </select>
                <div class="input-group-addon input-group-button">
                    <button type="button" id="show-contact-modal-button" class="btn btn-primary">Add contact</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- // Contacts -->
    <!-- // Referrer -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Create
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.input-group-button {
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    border-color: transparent;
    background: none;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/48pn9svy/)**

*PS. You appear to have placed the Referrer `text-right` button **INSIDE** your select element. This wont work, and should be updated*

**Update**

If you would like your button to feel more "attached" to the select, you'll have to "turn off" webkits default `border-radius` that overrides `.input-group .form-control`'s `border-radius`, but then can do something like:

[image]

**CSS**

```
.input-group-button {
    padding: 0;
    border:none;
    background: none;
}
.input-group .input-group-button:first-child .btn{
    border-top-right-radius:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0;
}
.input-group .input-group-button:last-child .btn{
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
}
.input-group select.form-control{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

**[Updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48pn9svy/1/)**

*Note: this will remove the browser added "arrows", so may not be what you're after*

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly detailed reply. I'm going with your first option because it's short and sweet and I guess the arrows will be useful for now. The styling is going to change anyway as I move to select2.

The only annoying thing with solution 1 is that the dropdown height is about a pixel smaller than the button height, so the button looks like it slightly hangs to the bottom. Nevertheless I need a really simple solution and your answer is it.

Comment: The CSS provided here will style _all_ instances of .`input-group-button`, whether added on to a `select` or a text `input`. To have this CSS _only_ apply to `select` lists, use `select + .input-group-button`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="contact_id" class="col-md-2 control-label"> Contact</label>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="contact_id" id="contacts-select" class="form-control" title="">
                <option value="1"
                    >
                    Eugene van der Merwe
                </option>
                <option value="2"
                    >
                    Person B
                </option>
                <option value="3"
                    >
                    Person C
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" id="show-contact-modal-button" class="btn btn-primary">
                Add contact
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- // Contacts -->

<!--Referrer -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="referrer_id" class="col-md-2 control-label"> Referrer</label>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <select name="referrer_id" id="referrers-select" class="form-control" title="">
                <option value="1"
                    > Eugene van der Merwe
                </option>
                <option value="2"
                    > Person B
                </option>
                <option value="3"
                    > Person C
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button id="show-referrer-modal-button" class="btn btn-primary">
                Add referrer
            </button>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
<!-- // Referrer -->
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Create
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</form >
```

i put select in div col-md-6 and the button in div with col-md-6

https://jsfiddle.net/walidazouzi/a0s6bjaL/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Contacts -->
<div class="form-group">
<label for="contact_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">Contact</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li>
    <select name="contact_id" id="contacts-select" class="form-control" title="">
                        <option value="1"
                            >
                Eugene van der Merwe</option>
                        <option value="2"
                            >
                Person B</option>
                        <option value="3"
                            >
                Person C</option>
                </select>
</li>
<li>
    <button type="button" id="show-contact-modal-button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add contact
    </button>
</li>
</ul>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- // Contacts -->
```

I found this code in Bootstrap 4. Please try these code. 



.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- try this -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="http://host/lead">
<!-- Contacts -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="contact_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">Contact</label>
     <div class="col-md-8">
         <select name="contact_id" id="contacts-select" class="form  control" title="">
<option value="1">
  Eugene van der Merwe
</option>
<option value="2">
  Person B
</option>
<option value="3">
  Person C
</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<button type="button" id="show-contact-modal-button" class="btn btn-primary">
Add contact
</button>
</div>
</div>
<!-- // Contacts -->

<!-- Referrer -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="referrer_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">Referrer</label>
     <div class="col-md-8">
       <select name="referrer_id" id="referrers-select" class="form-control" title="">
       <option value="1">Eugene van der Merwe</option>
       <option value="2">Person B</option>
       <option value="3">Person C</option>
       </select>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Create
     </button>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```