# How to align bootstrap text-box and button in one line?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-ui

I want to align textbox and button in one line. I am using bootstrap css. Below is the code i am using.

HTML :

```
<div class="new-meows">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        <button type="button" class="btn">Submit</button>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.new-meows{
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   margin : 10px;
   width: 97%;
 }
```

Layout it makes :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQyii.png)

I want the button just after the text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give proper width to textbox and button.
Lets say I want button to take width of 80px and rest to textbox.
Then it could be like this.

```
.new-meows{
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   margin : 10px;
   width: 97%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content:space-between;

 }
 .new-meows button{
    width: 80px;
 }
.new-meows input{
    width: calc(100% - 80px)
 }
```

using flex space-between you can achieve this. You can use float also.

Comment: your, welcome.. this is non bootstrap way.
You can view bootstrap way of doing this at this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615872/bootstrap-align-input-with-button

Answer (score 0):

Using `<div class="d inline "`>
will work for you

Comment: where to put this <div> ?

Answer (score 0):

Both Button and Input are block elements, so they will, by default, take the whole available horizontal space. You can change both elements to inline-block, so you can define the width you want any one them to occupy. Try the following css

```
.new-meows input {display:inline-block;width:80%;}
.new-meows button {display:inline-block;width:15%;}
```

You can change the width to any value you want, but be sure that the sum is smaller than 100%. In fact, it should be less than about 95%, because between both elements there is an empty space that matters.

Comment: You can also use px, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is going to be similar to @No one given, but there is a slight difference in mine. No need of `justify-content:space-between;`, and use `flex:1` instead of `width: calc(100% - 80px)`. `flex1` property will automatically assign the remaining width instead of calculating the width.

```css
.new-meows{
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   margin : 10px;
   width: 97%;
   display:flex;
 }
 .new-meows input {
   flex:1
 }
 .new-meows button {
   width:80px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="new-meows">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" >
        <button type="button" class="btn">Submit</button>    
</div>
```